# Does the performance of GBM methods profit from feature scaling?

Tags: feature-scaling, gbm

I know that [feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) is an important pre-processing step for creating artificial neural network models.

But what about [Gradient Boosting Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting), such as LightGBM, XGBoost or CatBoost? Does their performance profit from feature scaling? If so, why and how?

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I think the answer in this thread is better.  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/16225/55122

Comment: Also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/60950/55122

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scaling doesn't affect the performance of any tree-based method, not for lightgbm, xgboost, catboost or even a decision tree.

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244507/what-algorithms-need-feature-scaling-beside-from-svm/252625) that elaborates on the topic, but mainly the issue is that decision trees split the feature space based on binary decisions like "is this feature bigger than this value?", and if you scale your data, the decisions might look different, as they are done on the scaled space, but the results should be the same.

As an example, a decision tree should split in the same way the data if you change units (a particular case of scaling). Let's say you want to use weight of a person to predict if someone is under 18 (as a binary classifier). If given the weight in grams, the decision tree might do something like: if weight < 5000 grams, then the person is under 18. If you change the units to kilograms, the decision tree will do: if weight < 5 kg, then the person is under 18.

To sum up, the splits will be equivalent under any scaling or, in general, any increasing linear transformation.

Comment: Monotone transformations are a little trickier, since the splitting point may be chosen at or between two values of a feature in the training set, depending on the implementation.  The model will perform the same on the transformed training set, but an unseen test set may get different predictions from the original model and the transformed-training model.

Comment: You're right. It shouldn't happen with linear transformations though, right?

Comment: For _increasing_ (i.e. positive slope) linear functions like most/all scalers, yes everything about the model will be the same in the transformed space.  See also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/32638/55122