# Is it possible to do Normalization before Xgboost?

Tags: python, xgboost, normalization

Currently I am working on a project which uses Xgboost Regression.

Before putting data into model, I implemented Normalization, the accuracy significantly increased compared with without Normalization.

But I saw someone said that Xgboost doesn’t need Normalization .

Did someone meet the same issue as I met ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you perform normalization before or after train test split?

Comment: Feature scaling should have zero effect on the model (see e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/77312/55122); could you elaborate on your process?

Answer (score 1):

Xgboost is an ensemble algorithm based on decision trees, so doesn't need normalization.
You can check this on Xgboost official github: [Is Normalization necessary?](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/357) and this post [What are the implications of scaling the features to xgboost?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353462/what-are-the-implications-of-scaling-the-features-to-xgboost)

I'm new in this algorithm but I'm pretty sure of what I've written